# I am using Poetry for python package dependency

Tags: python-poetry

I am using poetry on my project.
but I have encountered an import module error when importing the redis package.

When i install the redis package from pip, that install is successful and the import module is successful too.

But poetry can't import the redis module.

What can I do solve this problem? Has anyone encountered the same problem?

Comment: that probably means that the environment you're using to run the code is not the same that poetry uses to install dependencies into. For example if you're using `sudo` to run your code. Do you know and understand the idea behind [virtual environments](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/)?

Comment: @Arne 
Thank you for your reply.
I solved this problem because of you.
As you said, this problem occurs in the configuration.

Comment: glad I could help =)